# Java servlet - any built-in way to restrict access to username/password?

Tags: java, security, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have an app engine java app. I'm defining my servlets in web.xml as usual, something like:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.me.MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/private/dangerous</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

It works fine. Is there any "built-in" security available for us? I don't want to allow access to the above servlet, it's an admin thing that only I should have access to. Do I build some simple username/password deal myself?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a security mechanism in web.xml, security constraints, that might work for a relatively simple case. You can find information on how to use this mechanism with GAE at : http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml.html#Security_and_Authentication

Comment: Ah this is perfect, lets me authenticate with my google account, thanks!

Comment: perfect if you run on app engine.  awful if you don't as migrating might be a touch involved.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a filter would be a good way to tackle it.  You can check the user's role, using basic auth, and allow or deny access as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You normally use a security-constraint in the web.xml for this.